Why is the liquid in my liquid domain not touching the edges?
I am trying to get a fairly simple liquid "splash" effect, but I'm getting very confused because I don't fully understand how this system is supposed to work and every video/tutorial appears to be for a different version of Blender (I'm using 4.1.)
I have a Liquid Domain object and within it I have a simple disk which is configured as an Inflow source like this:

My domain object is drawing the particles (using the Particles > Spray option) - it's base configuration is like this:

However when I try to run it, the liquid does not appear to come from anywhere near the source, appearing down in the bottom half of the domain object, and then it seems to slosh around but miles away from the edges of the object, as if it's in a cube half the size of my domain object.

What is going on here? Why isn't my liquid going to the edge of my Liquid Domain like it seems to do for everyone else?

I'd try to set the origin of the source to its center, and also check that the dimensions of the objects are comparable to the gravity value.
